How can I make notepad++ display the tab stops as specified in the language settings?
The vertical lines shown in notepad++ every 4 spaces, when I select python as the language they change to every 8 spaces, the tab ley actually inserts 4 spaces but the vertical lines do not show every 4 but every 8 spaces, how can I change this?

If i open a new blank text document with no language selected, the vertical lines do appear every 4 spaces or whatever quantity I use in the tab settings. with python only the tab stops change but the vertical bars remain at 8.


I see them every 4 spaces in your screenshot. In line 92, one vertical bar is on the left edge of the "f" in line 92, and the next is on the left edge of the "s" in line 92. Those are four apart. What am I missing?

Looks like it is set to 4 spaces but does it really make any difference since you are using 2 space indentation?

@Dough Count the number of dots, it may appear they are 4 spaces away because of the proportional font used, but as you can see, there are 8 dots between every vertical marker.

@cup tab is set to 4, but vertical lines show every 8, yes it makes a difference with python an indenting as its not easy to see when some line is not properly indented, and this causes errors in python.
